# Laravel 5 Queries really slow

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and im not sure if i am doing something incorrect as my queries take extremely long to run.

I have around 35000 records, please see below an example of a query that takes around 23 seconds to load the page (see screenshot link below).

[Screenshot](http://www.screencast.com/t/8xA9EamOinoM)

Can anyone advise on my mistake or a better way to query my DB. I have tried Eloquent and its a few ms slower than a DB:: Query.

```
$data3 = DB::table('toutcome')

            ->where('CompletedDate', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
           ->join('tapplicant', 'tapplicant.AppID', '=', 'toutcome.AppID')
            ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(CompletedDate, "%d %M %Y") as CompletedDate, 
                              SUM(AffID = "MW0050") as leadccount50,
                              SUM(AffID = "MW0051") as leadccount51, tapplicant.AppReference'))
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(CompletedDate, "%d %M %Y")'))
            ->get();
```

Comment: do you know the concept of mysql query cache. try to implement it,. first time it will take time to execute but next time you call a same query it will execute approx 3x faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly that sounds really long.

The queries do look quite detailed, but it shouldn't take longer than 1 minute.

You could try using eloquent, but this will be only a little quicker than the raw queries.

Things you didn't mention are :

Is this a local server or remote server ? If you are using a remote server, my solution would be to use the "skip-name-resolve" in your my.ini / my.cnf under mysqld and update your key_buffer_size.

If this does not improve the speed, maybe look at your resources for that particular server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the raw query directly in the database? If the query also is slow there you could try using EXPLAIN on it to help find where to add indexes and where to rewrite. Without knowing how your tables look my first guess is that the slowdown is related to the group by part